# Why can't I intercept write(2) in bash with LD_PRELOAD?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

---

OK, I get it. You can't override with LD_PRELOAD a libc function when it's called by another libc function.

---

I was playing with the Dante socksifier and noticed that it doesn't work with bash /dev/udp FDs. Then I wrote a simple .so file with the `write` function, and it doesn't work with bash too:
`libtest.c`:

```
#include <unistd.h>
ssize_t write(int fildes, const void *buf, size_t nbyte)
{
  return nbyte;
}
```

`test.c`:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  write(1,"abc\n",4);
  return 0;
}
```

_

```
$ gcc -g -O0 -fPIC -shared -o libtest.so libtest.c
$ gcc -g -O0 -o test test.c
$ ./test
abc
$ LD_PRELOAD=./libtest.so ./test
$ LD_PRELOAD=./libtest.so bash -c 'echo abc'
abc
```

upd: according to ensc, it has something to do with symbol versions.

What needs to be changed in linking ./test so it would fail just like bash? I mean, with the same .so file the command: `$ LD_PRELOAD=./libtest.so ./test` would print "abc", because `test` would bind to a versioned `write` in glibc.

I'm also trying the opposite - make a .so file with the versioned `write`. `version.script`:

```
GLIBC_2.2.5 {
    write;
};
```

But my library still can't intercept `write` in bash

```
$ gcc -g -O0 -fPIC -shared -Wl,--version-script=./version.script -o libtest.so libtest.c
$ LD_PRELOAD=./libtest.so bash -c 'echo abc'
abc
```

Comment: It is [`write(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) in the section 2 for [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) - there is no `write(3)`; BTW, some clever program might do a direct syscall -e.g. with [syscall(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) or with `SYSENTER` machine instruction, without even using the thin `write(2)` wrapper. Then you need [ptrace(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch By the way, doesn't the signature of the C function `write()` mimic 1:1 that of the `write` syscall?

Comment: More or less yes, but a raw syscall (thru `SYSENTER`) gets its arguments differently (thru registers) and is giving error codes quite differently. My point was that a `LD_PRELOAD` solution is not bullet-proof.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you look at the used symbols, you will probably see that versioned symbols are used for `write`:

```
$ readelf -a test | grep write
48: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND write@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

You have to write a linker script with a VERSION section (info ld -> "Version command").

Your case (manipulating bash behavior) is more complex because bash calls printf(3) which in turn uses some internal functions of libc.  When you have luck and a weak internal function is called (afais, there is only '__write'), you can overload it in your library.

Else, you have to override the printf() called by bash; you can find it out with 'ltrace'; e.g.:

```
$ ltrace  bash -c 'echo abc'
__printf_chk(1, "%s", "abc")                                  = 3
_IO_putc('\n', 0x7fc5eeac3420abc
```

or by setting LD_DEBUG (--> man ld.so)

Comment: I didn't know about linker scripts

Comment: What has to be changed in linking `./test` so it would fail just like bash?

Comment: I checked with gdb. In the end `write` is called from libc.